# How do I "download" history messages on Guupshup's WhatsApp?

Tags: database, api, download, whatsapp, gupshup

One of trainees here deleted all messages on our database (related to gupshup). How to download all messages sent/received from Gupshup (WhatsApp)? Is there an API?

Comment: Sorry Vinicius, we don't store messages due to privacy issues. There's no API for that.

Comment: Is there a way to get the quantity of messages per day using an API?